# Given graph G, find # of paths of lengh 2

Tags: graph-theory

I'm solving this graph theory problem:

> Let $G$ be a graph on $10$ vertices of degrees $1,1,2,3,3,3,4,4,5,8$. How many paths of length $2$ does $G$ contain?
>
> (Reminders: A path of length $2$ from vertex $a$ to vertex $b$ is defined as a sequence of two edges $a\text{---}v$ and $v\text{---}b$, where $v$ is some vertex. We do not require $a$ and $b$ to be distinct. If $a$ and $b$ are distinct, then the path $a\text{---}v\text{---}b$ is considered distinct from the path $b\text{---}v\text{---}a$.)

I'm not sure where to start. I've tried to list paths, but there is some overlap, and the graph is too big to draw. How should I approach this problem?

Thanks.

Comment: I'm assuming that the edges need to be distinct, and that this isn't a simple graph?

Comment: $a--v--a$ would count as a path if thats what your asking..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HINT: Each edge of $G$ contributes two out-and-back paths of length $2$. Each path of length $2$ that is not out-and-back has a vertex at its midpoint that it enters by one edge and leaves by another; thus, each vertex of degree greater than $1$ and each pair of edges incident at that vertex give rise to two more paths of length $2$, one in each direction.

Comment: What do out-and-back paths mean?

Comment: @Mark: Just what it sounds like: a path that starts at some vertex, goes to another, and returns along the same edge.

Comment: I got the answer, thanks a lot!

Comment: @Mark: Excellent; you’re welcome!

Comment: @BrianM.Scott  Is the answer $64$?

Comment: @Regina: I count quite a bit more than that. For instance, there are $\binom82=28$ pairs of edges incident at the vertex of degree $8$, and that already means $2\cdot28=56$ paths of length $2$ with that vertex as midpoint.

Comment: @Regina: I count $120$ that are not out-and-back plus $34$ that are, for a total of $154$. The sum of the degrees is $34$, so there are $17$ edges, each accounting for two out-and-back paths. Then we have $$2\left(\binom22+3\binom32+2\binom42+\binom52+\binom82\right)\;,$$ which is $2(1+9+12+10+28)=120$.

Comment: Okay, now I get what I had wrong.  Thanks!

Comment: @Regina: You’re welcome!

Answer (score 1):

Let $v$ be a vertex of $G$, and let $d$ be the degree of $v$. Then there are $d^2$ paths of the form $a\text{---}v\text{---}b$, because there are $d$ choices for vertex $a$ and $d$ choices for vertex $b$.

Therefore, if the vertices of $G$ have degrees $d_1,d_2,\ldots,d_n,$ then the number of paths of length $2$ is $d_1^2+d_2^2+\cdots+d_n^2$. In this case, that number is
$$1^2+1^2+2^2+3^2+3^2+3^2+4^2+4^2+5^2+8^2=\boxed{154}.$$